# How to rotate the video to landscape mode on button click?

Tags: android, android-videoview

i have video placed in VideoView and a button . i want that when the button is clicked , the video rotate to landscape mode and fit the screen of device! 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the screen orientation.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           //This line will set the orientation to landscape. 
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

You just need to use the values from the ACTIVITYINFO class.

**Resources**

ActivityInfo: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

Landscape: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

Portrait: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT